# How to navigate horizontally in a Helm buffer?

Tags: helm, motion

When I use `helm-occur` it prints the path to the source file of the buffer, which is inconvenient on a small display.

1. How can I navigate horizontally?
2. How can I hide paths in a helm buffer?

Comment: `helm-occur` doesn't display the paths for me. As for long lines, maybe disabling `truncate-lines` them will fit you best.